# Oracle SQL | Auto incremented ID is not incremented when an id is provided

Tags: sql, oracle, identity-column

I have following incrementing id:

```
create table PATIENT (
   PATIENTID            INTEGER             
      generated by default on null as identity ( start with 1 nocycle order)  not null
);
```

I noticed that, when I provide an id ( for example on my first inserts) the id in the created sequence does not increment.

As a result if I add a patient with id 1 and after that one with id NULL I get an error.

Is there a way to avoid this? Or do I have to remove all ID's from my insert scripts?

Comment: don't provide a value.  that is the purpose of the sequence.  You can't do both.  The insert will use whatever you pass in, and does nothing with the sequence at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a (non-null) value for the identity column, the sequence stays at the same value. This means the identity can try and insert a value you provided manually.

There are a couple of paths you could take here

Never supply values for the identity column. Set it as `generated always` to ensure no-one can do this:

```
create table patient (
   patientid integer             
      generated always as identity (
        start with 1 nocycle order
      )  not null primary key
);

insert into patient 
  values ( 1 );
  
ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
```

Allow scripts to provide values, but reset the identity's sequence to the columns maxvalue immediately after using `alter table`:

```
drop table  patient 
  cascade constraints purge;
create table patient (
   patientid integer             
      generated by default on null as identity (
        start with 1 nocycle order
      )  not null primary key
);

insert into patient 
  values ( 1 );
insert into patient 
  values ( 11 );
commit;

insert into patient 
  values ( default );
  
ORA-00001: unique constraint (CHRIS.SYS_C0024892) violated
  
alter table patient 
  modify patientid  
  generated by default on null as identity (
     start with limit value 
  );

insert into patient 
  values ( default );

select * from patient;

PATIENTID   
           1 
          11 
          12
```